# Can I still have BOOT_COMPLETED even if I don't launch the app after reboot?

Tags: java, android, bootcompleted

So let's say my receivers and service are correct, will the `BOOT_COMPLETED` still run even after I reboot the device and I won't open/launch it (the app) for the first time? Then the alarm works when its due date and time?

**NOTE**: I do not try to launch the app after the reboot.

this is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:persistent="true">
  <receiver android:name="com.majimechibireminder2.OnBootReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

  <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
   <service android:name=".ChibiReminderService" >
 </service>
   <activity android:name=".ChibiRemind"></activity>
</application>
```

If not, could you suggest me some proper code to work on those my ideals.

Comment: The app needs to be launched at least once for the `BOOT_COMPLETE` to work.

Comment: Is there no other way? what if the schedule of the user will be nearly on the scheduled date and time, and still the user don't run/launch the app for the first time after the reboot?

Comment: Your alarms set via AlarmManager will go away after the reboot.

Comment: Yes I know, but the problem is after the reboot the user probably won't run/launch the app for the first time then his/her schedule won't alarm, so I'm asking the other way to make onboot receiver to work even if the user won't run the app.

Comment: OK...you don't need to launch the app each time after the reboot to receive `BOOT_COMPLETE`...as long as the app doesn't do ANR or quit unexpectedly....it should receive `BOOT_COMPLETE` EACH time....no need to reopen

Comment: I have updated my answer. Take a look at it and please let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 1):

Your app needs to be lanuched at least once after it was installed to phone to make it able to receive broadcasts. If you are working with alarms you don't need to worry about it because the user will need to open app to set particular alarm.

When the phone gets turned off, alarms will go off. After reboot is completed your app will receive `BootCompleted` action. No need to launch app after reboot.

If the user doesn't open your app after it has being installed it means he/she didn't set any alarms. Therefore, no need to worry about reboot for such cases as there is nothing to reset after reboot.

**Update:**

Try adding attribute `android:enabled="true"` to your receiver. Final code should look something like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: hmm, I tried to set an alarm then reboot the device, I do not open the app, I waited for such until time then 1 minute passed from scheduled alarm, the alarm doesn't trigger.

Comment: What the code inside of `OnBootReceiver` does? Are you resetting alarms there?

Comment: I start intent service class, I reset all the alarms in the service class then reschedule them. I was able to reschedule the alarms IF I launch the app after the device reboots but if I don't launch the app the alarms won't be scheduled.

Comment: @AngelicaMaeRentoria I have updated my answer. Take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Alarms set by AlarmManager will be lost after a reboot (without any additional manipulation).

This is one area where JobScheduler APIs comes to the rescue. They are not lost after reboots if you set them to persist after reboots.